# Can you compare T elements?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm making a function that can take in T elements and compare them. However, whenever I try to compare T elements, I get a CS0019. It says

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

```
public static void Test<T>(T test1, T test2)
        {
            if(test1 == test2)
            {
              ...
            }
        }
```

I thought it would be a common mistake, but had trouble finding ways to fix it. Just to help you, I found a Comparer<T> thing but it didn't look to helpful. If you think you'll understand it, you can try. Thanking in advance!

Comment: Use `where T : IEquatable<T>`

Comment: Test1.Equals(Test2)

Comment: The compiler can't determine whether `==` and `!=` have been implemented for `T`, so you have to fall back to `.Equals`.

Comment: I'd recommend using `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to avoid boxing for structs though.

Comment: @JonSkeet If I'm not mistaken, `where T : IEquatable<T>` will not actually box, the callsite uses `constrained.callvirt` so no boxing. See https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANmgExAGoAfAAQCYBGAWAChyBmAAipYGEWBvBl/tq2AQIuFgFkAPABUAfAAppLAIZoWS4AEoWAdwAWMWOpABJAKIBHAK7KMy4LhgzZfAb3oDPbAOwqAdJY2uADO8loA3K78AL4M0UA===

Comment: This is splitting hairs, but what you do mean by "compare?" You mentioned that you tried using `==` but the question suggests that you just want to compare. Do you mean comparing to see both are references to the same object, if the properties have the same values, or something else?

Comment: @Charlieface: Yes, if you are able to constrain it that way. The beauty of `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` is that you don't need to constrain the type parameter... it will use the `IEquatable<T>` implementation if it's available, but it can work with any type.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `==` or `!=` it has to be implemented as an operator on the type. When using generics, the compiler doesn't know whether those operators have been implemented hence the compiler error, therefore you have to fall back to using `Equals`; for example:

```cs
public static void Test<T>(T test1, T test2)
{
    if(test1.Equals(test2))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that the above will only *correctly* determine equality if `Equals` on type `T` has been implemented correctly.